# Простой алгоритм генерации лабиринта на C/C++

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Нужен относительно простой в реализации алгоритм для генерации лабиринта с одним входом и одним выходом на C/C++. Единственность правильного пути не является обязательным условием.

Конечной целью является генерация лабиринта для простенькой игры в текстовом режиме.

Удобнее всего было бы, чтобы стены обозначались, например, знаком "#", а проходы, например, пробелом.

Comment: @Abyx Изобрести велосипед всегда интересно и приятно, но, полагаю, не я первый задаюсь этим вопросом, и не я последний. Если у меня получится сделать свою реализацию раньше, чем мне ответят здесь - отвечу на вопрос сам. Вопрос задал с надеждой, что кто-то подскажет алгоритм или покажет пример кода.

Comment: Перед тем, как задать вопрос, может быть стоило провести поиск в интернете? Все таки алгоритмы бывают разные и подобные задачи достаточно хорошо описаны: http://habrahabr.ru/post/176671/ В любом случае я думаю, если Вы напишите ответ на свой же вопрос, лишним это не будет.

Comment: @AlexKrass Я читал эту статью, как и некоторые другие (не стал об этом писать в тексте вопроса, т.к. это не по существу). Конкретно в этой статье - прекрасное описание алгоритма Эллера, но мне он показался слишком сложным для простой задачи, хотя и позволяет построить "идеальный" лабиринт. Постараюсь на досуге сделать реализацию этого алгоритма и посмотреть, что получится. Но всё же хотелось чего-нибудь до безобразия простого :-)

Comment: @SergeyPopov Пожалуйста укажите конкретную проблему, из-за котрой вы не можете решить свою задачу, вопрос в такой формулировке не соотвествует тематике РУСО и будет скорее всего закрыт.

Comment: @Cerbo чем вопрос и генерации лабиринта не является конкретным и не соответствует тематике? Если вы считаете, что его надо закрыть, можете воспользоваться соответсвующей кнопкой под вопросом. Как по мне, все нормально и у меня даже будет ответ по нему готов сегодня.

Comment: @AlexKrass Тем что в данной фомулировке вопрос не ставит какую-либо техническую проблему. То есть суть вопроса сейчас в том, что человеку нужен алгоритм.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Описание лабиринтов, их характеристик и алгоритмов можно [посмотреть здесь](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm). Их довольно разнообразное количество с различными характеристиками.

Поскольку алгоритм требуется довольно простой, то я решил взять алгоритм под названием "Growing Tree", его прекрасное описание и реализацию я [подсмотрел здесь](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/27/maze-generation-growing-tree-algorithm).

Его суть заключается в том, что выбирается случайная клетка и от нее строится путь по не посещенным клеткам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рано или поздно вы утыкаетесь в тупик, тогда начинается движение назад и поиск новых не посещенных клеток.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге, после таких манипуляций вы получите сеть ходов, которые складываются в лабиринт. Остается только проделать дырки для начала или конца или использовать клетки по своему усмотрению.

К сожалению я уже подзабыл С++, поэтому возможно есть некоторые ошибки и я не могу сделать быстро визуализацию на нем. Поэтому к ответу добавлена реализация на C# WPF + рендеринг в Canvas получившегося с картинками)

**[C++]**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum CellState { Close, Open };
class Cell
{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        CellState Left;
        CellState Right;
        CellState Top;
        CellState Bottom;
        bool Visited;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int width = 5,
              height = 5;

    Cell labyrinth[width][height];

    //заполняем начальные данные для ячеек
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            labyrinth[x][y].x = x;
            labyrinth[x][y].y = y;
            labyrinth[x][y].Visited = false;
        }

    //Выбираем первую ячейку откуда начнем движение
    srand(time(NULL));
    int startX = rand() % width;
    int startY = rand() % height;

    labyrinth[startX][startY].Visited = true;

    //Заносим нашу ячейке в path и начинаем строить путь
    stack<Cell> path;
    path.push(labyrinth[startX][startY]);

    while (!path.empty())
    {
        Cell _cell = path.top();

        //смотрим варианты, в какую сторону можно пойти
        vector<Cell> nextStep;
        if (_cell.x > 0 && (labyrinth[_cell.x - 1][_cell.y].Visited == false))
            nextStep.push_back(labyrinth[_cell.x - 1][_cell.y]);
        if (_cell.x < width - 1 && (labyrinth[_cell.x + 1][_cell.y].Visited == false))
            nextStep.push_back(labyrinth[_cell.x + 1][_cell.y]);
        if (_cell.y > 0 && (labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y - 1].Visited == false))
            nextStep.push_back(labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y - 1]);
        if (_cell.y < height - 1 && (labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y + 1].Visited == false))
            nextStep.push_back(labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y + 1]);

        if (!nextStep.empty())
        {
            //выбираем сторону из возможных вариантов
            Cell next = nextStep[rand() % nextStep.size()];

            //Открываем сторону, в которую пошли на ячейках
            if (next.x != _cell.x)
            {
                if (_cell.x - next.x > 0)
                {
                    labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y].Left = Open;
                    labyrinth[next.x][next.y].Right = Open;
                }
                else
                {
                    labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y].Right = Open;
                    labyrinth[next.x][next.y].Left = Open;
                }
            }
            if (next.y != _cell.y)
            {
                if (_cell.y - next.y > 0)
                {
                    labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y].Top = Open;
                    labyrinth[next.x][next.y].Bottom = Open;
                }
                else
                {
                    labyrinth[_cell.x][_cell.y].Bottom = Open;
                    labyrinth[next.x][next.y].Top = Open;
                }
            }

            labyrinth[next.x][next.y].Visited = true;
            path.push(next);

        }
        else
        {
            //если пойти никуда нельзя, возвращаемся к предыдущему узлу
            path.pop();
        }
    }

    //... где-то тут визуализируем labyrinth...

    return 0;
}
```

**[C# WPF]**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        enum CellState { Close, Open };
        class Cell 
        {
            public Cell(Point currentPosition) 
            {
                Visited = false;
                Position = currentPosition;
            }

            public CellState Left { get; set; }
            public CellState Right { get; set; }
            public CellState Bottom { get; set; }
            public CellState Top { get; set; }
            public Boolean Visited { get; set; }
            public Point Position { get; set; }
        }

        private Int32 _Width, _Height;
        private Cell[,] Cells;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(e);
            _Width = 10;
            _Height = 10;
            Cells = new Cell[_Width, _Height];

            for (int y = 0; y < _Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < _Width; x++)
                    Cells[x, y] = new Cell(new Point(x, y));

            Random rand = new Random();
            Int32 startX = rand.Next(_Width);
            Int32 startY = rand.Next(_Height);

            Stack<Cell> path = new Stack<Cell>();

            Cells[startX, startY].Visited = true;
            path.Push(Cells[startX, startY]);

            while (path.Count > 0)
            {
                Cell _cell = path.Peek();

                List<Cell> nextStep = new List<Cell>();
                if (_cell.Position.X > 0 && !Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X - 1), Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y)].Visited)
                    nextStep.Add(Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y)]);
                if (_cell.Position.X < _Width - 1 && !Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X) + 1, Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y)].Visited)
                    nextStep.Add(Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X) + 1, Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y)]);
                if (_cell.Position.Y > 0 && !Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X), Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y) - 1].Visited)
                    nextStep.Add(Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X), Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y) - 1]);
                if (_cell.Position.Y < _Height - 1 && !Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X), Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y) + 1].Visited)
                    nextStep.Add(Cells[Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.X), Convert.ToInt32(_cell.Position.Y) + 1]);

                if (nextStep.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Cell next = nextStep[rand.Next(nextStep.Count())];

                    if (next.Position.X != _cell.Position.X)
                    {
                        if (_cell.Position.X - next.Position.X > 0)
                        {
                            _cell.Left = CellState.Open;
                            next.Right = CellState.Open;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _cell.Right = CellState.Open;
                            next.Left = CellState.Open;
                        }
                    }
                    if (next.Position.Y != _cell.Position.Y)
                    {
                        if (_cell.Position.Y - next.Position.Y > 0)
                        {
                            _cell.Top = CellState.Open;
                            next.Bottom = CellState.Open;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _cell.Bottom = CellState.Open;
                            next.Top = CellState.Open;
                        }
                    }

                    next.Visited = true;
                    path.Push(next);
                }
                else
                {
                    path.Pop();
                }
            }

            renderCells();
        }

        private void renderCells()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < _Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < _Width; x++)
                {
                    if (Cells[x, y].Top == CellState.Close)
                        mCanvas.Children.Add(new Line() 
                        {
                            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                            StrokeThickness = 1,
                            X1 = 20 * x,
                            Y1 = 20 * y,
                            X2 = 20 * x + 20,
                            Y2 = 20 * y
                        });

                    if (Cells[x, y].Left == CellState.Close)
                        mCanvas.Children.Add(new Line()
                        {
                            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                            StrokeThickness = 1,
                            X1 = 20 * x,
                            Y1 = 20 * y,
                            X2 = 20 * x,
                            Y2 = 20 * y + 20
                        });

                    if (Cells[x, y].Right == CellState.Close)
                        mCanvas.Children.Add(new Line()
                        {
                            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                            StrokeThickness = 1,
                            X1 = 20 * x + 20,
                            Y1 = 20 * y,
                            X2 = 20 * x + 20,
                            Y2 = 20 * y + 20
                        });

                    if (Cells[x, y].Bottom == CellState.Close)
                        mCanvas.Children.Add(new Line()
                        {
                            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                            StrokeThickness = 1,
                            X1 = 20 * x,
                            Y1 = 20 * y + 20,
                            X2 = 20 * x + 20,
                            Y2 = 20 * y + 20
                        });
                }
        }
    }
```

Примеры рендеринга:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]